# Querying emails that contains an individual

Tags: sql-server

I want to pull a conversation for a certain order that a person has ever read a message on. For instance:

```
Order  SentTOID  ReadBy  
A      111       55
A      55        55
A      111       89
B      111       89
C      111       55
C      55        55
D      111       99
D      99        99
```

Results

```
A      111       55
A      55        55
A      111       89
C      111       55
C      55        55
```

My code will only pull all the cases that were read by 55 but I want the whole converstaion.

```
Order  SentTOID  ReadBy  
A      111       55
A      55        55
C      111       55
C      55        55
```

Code used.

```
Select *
from conversation
where readby = 55.
```

Comment: Your not using a grouping function? Try calling the columns by name.  Select `Order`, `SentTOID`, ` ReadBy`
from conversation
where readby = 55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get Order and apply `IN` clause

```
declare @temp table
(Orders  nvarchar(7), SentTOID int, ReadBy  int)
insert into @temp values ('A',111,55)
insert into @temp values ('A',55 ,55)
insert into @temp values ('A',111,89)
insert into @temp values ('B',111,89)
insert into @temp values ('C',111,55)
insert into @temp values ('C',55 ,55)
insert into @temp values ('D',111,99)
insert into @temp values ('D',99 ,99)


select * from @temp
where Orders in (select Orders from @temp where ReadBy = 55)
```

RESULT

[image]